# ArcSDE Problems: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 2008 R2 Standard (64-Bit)

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arcgis-10.2, windows-server-2008

I´m trying to set up ArcSDE 10.2 on a  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64-Bit machine.
I can **create** the database connection, but when I want to **enable** it for spatial data I keep on getting the following error message:

```
Error: The version of your database server is not supported
ERROR installing/upgrading ArcSDE, Error = -494
```

This is strange because the [ESRI page on System Requirements](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#/Microsoft_SQL_Server_Database_Requirements/015100000070000000/) states, that this combination should work.

Any idea what I could do, to get it fixed?
Thanks

EDIT:

I´m using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 64-Bit, or at least that is what Windows tells me (see image). I´ve tried without SP, than with SP1 and then SP2. Neither option worked.

[image: Installed Eindows Programs]

Comment: Is your SQL-Server install 64-bit? Esri has been 64-bit only on databases for a while now.

Comment: SQL-Server is 64-Bit. Do you think that could be a problem?

Comment: Check again, since you wouldn't get that error if your database were compatible.

Comment: You also need to have SP1 applied.

Comment: I´m pretty sure it´s 64-Bit, or at least that is what Windows tells me (see my EDIT with picture). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Esri only supports SP1 of 2008 R2.

Comment: I tried both, first without, then SP1, then SP2. Unfortunately it´s not working. :-(

Comment: Then it's time to call Tech Support.

Comment: Try installing SP1 for your Windows Server 2008 R2, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842